# How to remove duplicate values from a multidimentional array according to a key

Tags: php, arrays

Simple question  have following code but won't work

```
//Enter your code here, enjoy!
$correo[] = array('valor'=>'vikram.123@gmil.com','registro'=>'23');
$correo[] = array('valor'=>'vikram.123@gmil.com','registro'=>'24');
$correo[] = array('valor'=>'vikram.123@gmil.com','registro'=>'26');

function arrayUnique($myArray){
    if(!is_array($myArray))
        return $myArray;

    foreach ($myArray as &$myvalue){
        $myvalue=serialize($myvalue);
    }

    $myArray=array_unique($myArray);

    foreach ($myArray as &$myvalue){
        $myvalue=unserialize($myvalue);
    }

    return $myArray;

} 

$arr= arrayUnique($correo);

var_dump($arr);
```

What I am trying to do is remove those row which has repetitive `valor` key for example the result of above array should be

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [valor] => 'vikram.123@gmail.com' 
        [registro] => 24 
        ) 
)
```

Comment: Which `registro` should be considered?

Comment: @b0s3 any one as of now

Comment: Can't see any duplicate values in registro..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the function like -

```
function arrayUnique($myArray){
    if(!is_array($myArray))
        return $myArray;
    $temp = array();
    foreach ($myArray as $myvalue){
        $temp[$myvalue['valor']] = $myvalue;
    }
    return $temp;
}
```

Store the array with `valor` as key. It will store only the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this...

```
$correo[] = array('valor'=>'vikram.123@gmil.com','registro'=>'23');
$correo[] = array('valor'=>'vikram.123@gmil.com','registro'=>'24');
$correo[] = array('valor'=>'vikram.123@gmil.com','registro'=>'26');
function arrayUnique($myArray, $uniqueKeyName)  
{ 
    // Unique Array for return  
    $myReturnArray = array();  
    // Array with the md5 hashes  
    $arrayHashes = array();  
    foreach($myArray as $key => $item) {        
        $hash = md5(serialize($item[$uniqueKeyName]));       
          if (!isset($arrayHashes[$hash])) {  
           $arrayHashes[$hash] = $hash;         
           $myReturnArray[] = $item;
        }  
    }  
    return $myReturnArray;  
} 
$arr= arrayUnique($correo, 'valor');
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);  
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this, since you said any one of `registro` should be considered.

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
 <?php

 $array = array(
                 array('valor'=>'vikram.123@gmil.com','registro'=>'23'),
                 array('valor'=>'vikram.123@gmil.com','registro'=>'24'),
                 array('valor'=>'vikram.123@gmil.com','registro'=>'26')
               );

 function remove_dup($array, $key)
 {
    foreach( $array as $v )
    {
        if(! isset($out[ $v[$key] ]  ) )
            $out[$v[$key]] = $v;
    }
    return array_values($out);
 }


 // Input
 print_r( $array );

 // Output
 print_r( remove_dup($array,'valor') );

 ?>
```

***Output***

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
 Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [valor] => vikram.123@gmil.com
             [registro] => 23
         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [valor] => vikram.123@gmil.com
             [registro] => 24
         )

     [2] => Array
         (
             [valor] => vikram.123@gmil.com
             [registro] => 26
         )

 )

 Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [valor] => vikram.123@gmil.com
             [registro] => 23
         )

 )
```